Arcade - problem with rule-based styling for more than one condition
I want to set the Arcade expression in my ArcGIS Online project, which will be based on more than one criterion. I need to include two fields instead of one as I can usually do in ArcGIS Online without using the expression.
I want to use the following fields:

and prepared the following Arcade code:
var field1Value = $feature.validation;
var field2Value = $feature.MOBRA;

if (field1Value == "Yes" && field2Value == "Yes") {
return {
    color: "#00ff00", // green
    size: 8
 };
 } else if (field1Value == "No" && field2Value == "Yes") {
   return {color: "#ffff00", // yellow
        size: 6};
 } else {
   return {color: "#0000ff", // blue
        size: 7};
 }

but unfortunately, I can't see any response. Moreover, I have styling based on the feature size instead, whereas the size isn't provided anywhere as the values are Yes/No/No Access.
Removing existing field-based symbology (which isn't colliding anyway) wasn't enough.

Is there any way of correct styling in this situation?

Arcade will not return values that directly create symbology. You have to take the returned values and manually set the color and symbol size in the styles editor (along with the proper label)
var field1Value = $feature.validation;
var field2Value = $feature.MOBRA;

if (field1Value == "Yes" && field2Value == "Yes") {
  return 'green';
} else if (field1Value == "No" && field2Value == "Yes") {
   return 'yellow';
} else {
   return 'blue';
}


It doesn't work as I see the command "There was an error".
